# Accessing TFS (on prem) via powershell in docker windows container

Tags: windows, tfs, dockerfile

I have a window 2016 server running windowservercore.  I am working on moving CI pipeline into containers.   During our process, we build a version.html file.  The file contains build data(like build date and build nbr) and TFS 2017 project information about merge/branch that have occured.

We had this working with TeamCity running a PowerShell script that would connect and run a query against TFS 2017.  So I looked on docker hub for TFS, but did not have any luck.   I also tried looking under Microsoft on docker hub and did not find anything.

I tried to create a new docker file

```
    FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1480

# Setup shell
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Mkdir BuildStage
COPY powershell/CopyBuildToStageDir.ps1 \BuildStage
Copy  powershell/BuildVersionFile.ps1 \BuildStage

RUN dir
```

But when I ran the Powershell file inside the windows container it said...

```
Unable to find type 

[09:25:00][Step 2/2] [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory].

[09:25:00][Step 2/2] At C:\BuildStage\BuildVersionFile.ps1:192 char:12
```

In the PowerShell, there is this function

```
#============================================================================
# Setup TFS stuff
#============================================================================
function Setup-Tfs {

    # Connect to TFS
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client") | out-null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client") | out-null

    $tfsServer =  "http://ourServer";
    $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($tfsServer) 
    $Script:versionControlServer = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer] ) 
    $Script:recursionType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full

}
```

Here are more details of how we are using powershell to call TFS to get Merge and Branch information to build the version.html file...

```
   # Need to get the last 5 changesets of Merge information for both MAIN and Iteration
    Setup-Tfs

    $baseLocation = "$/OurBaseLocation/"
    $locationForMain = $baseLocation + $OurProjectLocation

    # Query history for the TFS path
    $vCSChangeSets = $versionControlServer.QueryHistory($locationForMain, $recursionType, 5)

    # History of Merge changes to MAIN application (only 5 deep)
    "<table border='2'>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
    "<caption>Merge Info For: $AppName </caption>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append

    # Build out headers
    "<TH>Changeset</TH><TH>Date</TH><TH>Comment</TH>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append

    Foreach ($vCSChangeSet in $vCSChangeSets) {
        # write row
        $changeset =  $vCSChangeSet.ChangesetID 
        $CheckinNotesName =  $vCSChangeSet.Comment
        $CreationDate =  $vCSChangeSet.CreationDate

        if ($CheckinNotesName.ToUpper().Contains("MERGE")){
            "<TR>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
            "<TD>$changeset</TD><TD>$CreationDate</TD><TD>$CheckinNotesName</TD>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
            "</TR>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
        }
        if ($CheckinNotesName.ToUpper().Contains("BRANCH")){
            "<TR>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
            "<TD>$changeset</TD><TD>$CreationDate</TD><TD>$CheckinNotesName</TD>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
            "</TR>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
        }
    }

    # close table add space
    "</table><BR/><BR/>" | Out-File $VersionFname -append
```

My guess is that my docker file needs to add something for "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to create the file inside the container? Can't you generate it, then add it to the container? The purpose of the container is unclear.

Comment: @Daniel  CI stands for continuous integration.   Think automated builds.  So no it does not make sense to add a manual step to an automated process.   It looks in April 2017 Microsoft created a package for team explorer.   Still working on how to get the docker file to install it.   [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/05/reintroducing-the-team-explorer-standalone-installer/)

Comment: I am well aware of what continuous integration is. That doesn't answer the question of what role the container is serving during the CI process. My suggestion was to generate the file outside of the container, during the CI process, then add it to the container. If the idea is that you've containerized your build process, that was not stated or evident in the question.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: What specific information are you trying to retrieve from TFS? I ask because if all you need to do is query some data, the REST APIs are more appropriate. If you're trying to synchronize source code into the container via the object model, you might be going down the wrong path -- the better approach would be to containerize your build environment, then make a container based off of that with the appropriate build agent and a script to connect/configure it. Then your entire build environment is containerized and easy to scale out as necessary.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what we are pulling.   Basically, we are pulling the last 5 changesets for the project.   We are using the 
QueryHistory command in the namespace of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer

Answer (score 1):

What I found that worked best was to give up on the PowerShell namespaces for TFS.   Instead, use the TFS API.  Here is an example to get the properties of a single WI.

```
#============================================
# Get-TFSFieldsByWiId
#============================================
function Get-TFSFieldsByWiId([string]$Id) {

    $url = 'http://YourTFSUrl:YourPort/YourProject/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=' + $Id+'&$expand=all&api-version=YourVersion'

    # Step 1. Create a username:password pair
    $credPair = "$(''):$($password)"

    # Step 2. Encode the pair to Base64 string
    $encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))

    # Step 3. Form the header and add the Authorization attribute to it
    $headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }

    # Step 4. Make the GET request
    $responseData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing -Body ($QueryToRun|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"

    $data = $responseData.Content
    $data = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
    $WIDetails = $data.value
    return $WIDetails
}
```